# Thawte ssl 123 certificate installation on ubuntu 12, apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-12.04, mod-ssl

I have recently purchased the ssl123 certificate from thwate.
They have provided me following files
1:x.509 certificate
2:Apache Bundle
3:intermediate CA1

I am trying to install on my server but no success here are my configuration.

Virtual Host file

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost IP:443>
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/x.509.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/my.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/intermediate.crt
        ServerAdmin xyz@gmail.com
        ServerName  www.xyz.org
        ServerAlias xyz.org
        DocumentRoot /var/www/ecommerce/
        <Directory />
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/ecommerce/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</<IfModule>

     port.conf file

     NameVirtualHost *:80
     Listen 80

     <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
         # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
         # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
         # to <VirtualHost *:443>
         # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
         # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
         Listen 443
     </IfModule>

     <IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
         Listen 443
    </IfModule>
```

Apache Error Log

```
[Thu Aug 01 11:43:58 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Aug 01 11:43:59 2013] [warn] [mod_spdy/0.9.4.1-397] [7305:7305:WARNING:mod_spdy.cc(166)] mod_spdy is insta                        config. SPDY will not be used by this server.  See http://code.google.com/p/mod-spdy/wiki/ConfigOptions for ho
[Thu Aug 01 11:43:59 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Thu Aug 01 11:43:59 2013] [warn] RSA server certificate CommonName (CN) `Thawte DV SSL CA' does NOT match serv
[Thu Aug 01 11:43:59 2013] [error] Unable to configure RSA server private key
[Thu Aug 01 11:43:59 2013] [error] SSL Library Error: 185073780 error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_c
```

UPDATED CONFIG

```
[Thu Aug 01 13:09:03 2013] [error] Init: Multiple RSA server certificates not allowed
[Thu Aug 01 13:10:51 2013] [warn] [mod_spdy/0.9.4.1-397] [13606:13606:WARNING:mod_spdy.cc(166)] mod_spdy is installed, but has not been enabled in the Apache config. SPDY will not be used by this server.  See http://code.google.com/p/mod-spdy/wiki/ConfigOptions for how to enable.
```

VHOST File

```
IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost IP:443>
        SSLEngine On
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/x.509.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/my.key
        SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/rootcertificate.crt
        ServerAdmin xyz@gmail.com
        ServerName  www.xyz.org
        ServerAlias xyz.org
        DocumentRoot /var/www/ecommerce/
        <Directory />
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/ecommerce/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</<IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your certificate / private key or Root CA certificate is not matching.

You are using an intermediate certificate for the parameter SSLCACertificateFile. Please switch to the correct root CA certificate which will match your kind of certificate (e.g. "Thawte Premium Server CA". Link: [Thawte Root CA downloads](https://www.thawte.com/roots/index.html)

Btw: your apache logs seems to be truncated on the right side.

Comment: Mulitiple certificate not allowed

Comment: please post/update your config.

Comment: Please check the data below updated config..

Comment: I can't see a mistake in your config. Please check if there is any other vhost config active. Only one SSL certficate is allowed per IP.

Comment: Striker. My problem has been solved, after restarting the server.. But on my website on https written the connection of this website is partially encrypted..What is this.

Comment: Great News. Please check if there are any ressources (frames, etc) in your html files that reference http (not https). Please set your answer as solved. thanks